# Accessing the value returned by an object's method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

I have an object and I would like to loop through it and print out all the values of its properties. My problem is that when I try to print out the value returned by one of its methods, I get the code of the method instead of the value the method should return. I'm sure I'm making an access syntax typo, but I can't figure it out.

```
function Dog (breed,sound) {
    this.breed = breed;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.bark = function(){
        alert(this.sound); 
        return this.sound;
    };
}

var x = new Dog("Retriever",'woof');
x.bark(); // Test: 'woof'

for (var y in x) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML +="<br/>"+x[y];
}
/* x[y] when y is 'bark' returns the method's code,
   but I'm looking for the value. */
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nysteve/QHumL/4/

Comment: because it's a function and you need to call it with () at the end

Comment: I'm still confused, so there's no way to loop through all the properties of this object —using a loop —and print out their values when some of the properties are methods that return values?

Comment: use this (x[y] instanceof Function? x[y]():x[y]);

Comment: the way I used to detect if a property is function may be problematic...a better way is to use "Object.prototype.toString.call(your_variable) == '[object Function]';"

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you? The idea here also is to make this "bark" property more generic so you could possibly use this for other animals.

```
function Dog (breed,sound) {
  this.breed = breed;
  this.sound = sound;
  this.noise = alertNoise(this);
}

function alertNoise(animal) {
    alert(animal.sound); 
    return animal.sound;    
}

var x = new Dog("Retriever",'woof');
//x.bark(); // 'woof'

for (var y in x) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML +="<br/>"+x[y];
}
// x[y] when y is 'bark' returns the property-function's code, but I'm looking for the value.
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would do this either but it's exactly what the bark function is doing in OP's example.